# How to use ConnectionString with DbContext using Entity Framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with a Windows Forms Application and have added Entity Framework 6 to the project. I have created a class where I can pass in the table name so I can use one class with many different tables. I want to use EF Code First without the wizard. How do you set the connection string for the DbContext? I know in ASP.NET MVC you can set it in the app.Config file but this is a Windows Forms Application. How do you set the connection string in order to get the data from the SQL Server?

```
public class TimerContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _tableName;

    public TimerContext(string tableName) : base("name=TimerContext")
    {
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Timer>().ToTable(_tableName);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Timer> Timers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project, choose Add -> New Items -> Application config file.

Add you connection string in the newly created app.config file and you're done.